# How to find the branch points of this logarithmic function on a complex domain

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-points

Now that I know that the branch points of a function $\sqrt[n]{P(z)}$ can be determined by the integral division of the zero points of $P(z)$ by n.

Then how to find the branch points of this logarithmic function on a complex domain: $Ln(P(z))$, where $P(z)$ is a polynomial function like $z^3+2z^2+5 ...$, and $Ln(z)=ln|z|+iArgz,z\in\mathbb{C}$.

For example, branch points of $Ln(1-z^2)$ are $-1,+1,\infty$

Comment: zeroes and infinity are always branch points for the logarithm regardless of the order

Comment: @Conrad According to the example I gave, if 0 is not a zero point of the inner polynomial function, then it may not be a branch point. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes - the branch points are zeroes of $P$ and infinity

Comment: @Conrad Are all zero points branch points? Thank you~

Comment: Yes - for the logarithm since it has infinitely many local branches so you cannot go back with finitely many operations